# How can i achieve Multiline UILabel with NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle and sizeToFit in autolayout?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel, autolayout

I have a two line UILabel. I want its line break mode NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle. The problem i am getting is if text is small enough to fit in one line, its showing it in middle of label instead of at top. I am using iOS6 and autolayout so sizeToFit is not working for me.
How can i achieve this? I want if text is small to fit one line it should be vertically top aligned. **I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6), but its truncating and showing the text in one line only rather than two line.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the required size and update the frame of your label:

```
CGSize s = [myLabelString sizeWithFont:...
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(..., MAXFLOAT)
                         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle];
```

With whatever font your label is using and its width.

Comment: your answer if right, but one more thing is that if I took NSAttributedString, its truncating text in only one line though its taking size of two lines. I also tried setting line break mode of NSParagraphStyle in NSAttributedString but did't work. Can you please update on this also?

Comment: With attributed strings you should get the size with `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`.

Comment: Hi wain, i am getting the size using boundingRectWithSize:options:context: but still its truncating attributedString in one line if text is greater than one line. How should i use Label with two lines, NSAttributedString, NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle and sizeThatFits?

Comment: Have you set the number of lines on the label?

Comment: And you're setting the label size directly now? It could be a border related issue where the label doesn't actually have as much space for rendering the text as its frame may suggest. So you may need to set the frame a little bigger.

Comment: when i set the NSLineBreakByWordWrapping instead of NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle it correctly shows text on two line. So i dont think it is an frame issue. You can check some links
http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Nov/msg00180.html
http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Nov/msg00187.html

Comment: hmm, does the text happen to be just the length where that last word is the only part that should wrap? I don't have an actual answer now, it sounds a bit like a bug / feature of how the truncation is applied.