# How to let the width of an NSTextField be adjusted to its content?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

I work with `Xcode5`.

**I would like the width of my `NSTextField` to adapt to its content.**

If possible, I would like to do this in `InterfaceBuilder` and if possible, without subclassing.

EDIT :
I am working with `autolayout` ON !! (which seems to prevent me from changing the width of my NSTextField)

Comment: why is it that you need this? I may be able to give an alternate solution that could assists you, or at least help to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have a generic label : "Hello <name>". After this label, I have another `NSTextView`. I want the second one to be right after the first one.

Comment: I am not an auto layout expert, but it works with weights, so can't you assign a stronger weight to content fit than right edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation for a [NSTextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) there is nothing that shows that a `NSTextField` can resize depending on its content, so with that I assume it's impossible. For the kicks and giggles, though, I checked the storyboard and there is no property that allows your `NSTextField` to be resized besides the auto resizing mask, which have nothing to do with the `NSTextField` text attribute.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?  This is obviously not impossible and there are multiple ways you could choose to tackle this problem. `boundingRect(with size: NSSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], attributes: [String : Any]? = nil) -> NSRect` on `NSString` is one method you could start with.

Comment: When crafting the answer above, I was under the assumption that they wanted a no overhead approach such as resizing to intrinsic size. 

Autolayout is nothing more than a bunch of math calculations that you can always do yourself if you desire and with that logic everything is re-sizable.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:-
connect delegate to your textfield

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
    NSString *str=[yourTextField stringValue];
    NSCell *cell=[[NSCell alloc]initTextCell:str];
    CGFloat sz=[cell cellSize].width;
    [yourTextField setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(sz+10.0, 22.0)];
}
```

Comment: It works if `autolayout` is not active. But it doesn't work with `autolayout` ON... And I need `autolayout` !

Comment: Autolayout has a constraint called "intrinsic value" which means to set the label to the size of it's content. This is only for a UILabel so you can't type in it...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth for NSTextfield, this value will be used to update your height, I hope it is helpful.
And Reference resources:[UILabel sizeToFit doesn't work with autolayout ios6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6)