# How to make a container view's height dynamic based on auto layout constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout

I made a custom TableViewCell in Xcode interface builder, with a UILabel and a UITextView stacked vertically, and I set the constraints of vertical spacings between them and the container cell view.

[image]

The UITextView may need to hold a lot of text, I don't want vertical scrollbar to appear, so I calculate the height of the UITextView with [NSString sizeWithFont:constraintTosize:], and set its frame with this new height.

But it doesn't work.

Then I noticed the custom cell in .xib has a fixed row height. I am wondering if this fixed height and the vertical constraints determines the height of UITextView, and I cannot change it?

What if I want the other way around: When I set the height of UITextView, the height of the containing cell is calculated based on the constraints? Is this possible?

Comment: And BTW, I think in spite of Apple's efforts on UI layout with auto layout and so on, it is still much inferior compared to HTML/CSS box model.

Comment: UITableViewDelegate has a method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: - Calculate the height and return it from this method.

Comment: performance > easier layout

Comment: @0xSina Surely I can manually calculate the cell height, but that way the auto layout constraints would be useless, don't you think?

Comment: @NeoWant auto layout / constraints still work within a UITableViewCell (just like any other view)...but size of each cell is determined by UITableView's rowHeight or it's delegate. Why? It's just how UITableView works. It manages it's view hierarchy in this specific manner to make it very optimized/not laggy. Imagine a tableview with 100s of cells (very common). It would then how to loop through each cell, apply constraints and determine contentSize of itself...very inefficient and one of the reasons why HTML/CSS box model/webviews, though superior in your opinion, is very laggy/inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should be helpful. I was able to do what you're describing and account for variable amounts of text on a `UILabel`, inside a custom `UITableViewCell` called `CustomCell`. `CustomCell` uses the boilerplate `UITableViewCell` code with no modifications.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    // Using some sample text in here for testing purposes.
    NSString *sampleText = @"The UITextView may need to hold a lot of text, I don't want vertical scrollbar to appear. The UITextView may need to hold a lot of text, I don't want vertical scrollbar to appear.";

    cell.textLabel.text = sampleText;
    [cell.textLabel layoutIfNeeded];

    return cell.textLabel.frame.size.height;
}
```

Last but not least, set up your `UILabel` inside your `CustomCell` with AutoLayout. Follow this link to see steps on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16009707/885189