# Using autolayout to manage height of UILabel within a subview

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, xcode5

Using Xcode 5, interface builder and developing for iOS 7.

Within my content view I have 2 additional sub views, one on top of another. Within the upper subview I have a `UILabel`. I would like for that `UILabel` to expand in height when the content exceeds the first line, but I can't seem to get the height increase of the `UILabel` to increase the height of the subview, thus pushing the bottom subview down the main content view.

Additionally, I would assume the content view would need some sort of a constraint that reflects the overall height of the two subviews?

Perhaps this the question has already been answered somewhere, but I've searched everywhere and can't seem to come up with a solution.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of steps that you have to do to achieve this using `autolayout`.

1. Set layout constrains for the label.
2. Set `height` constraint with low priority.
3. Set `numberOfLines` to `0` to allow multiline text.
4. Set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for the label.

The `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is used by label to calculate its height.

> This property affects the size of the label when layout constraints
>   are applied to it. During layout, if the text extends beyond the width
>   specified by this property, the additional text is flowed to one or
>   more new lines, thereby increasing the height of the label.

Also, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6).