# UITableviewCell loads UILabel data after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm kind of new to **iOS** and the Issue i have right now is in the below screen shot. I have eight labels in each `UITableviewCell` which is a prototype cell. When the table loads first time it looks like this

[image]

But when I scroll down and up it loads the whole `UIlabel`s text as shown below

[image]

I'm manually assigning the coordinates based on the nearest top `UILabel`'s height.
I have tried to reload table, reload sections etc in `viewDidAppear` but no use as all the data is present before tableview datasource methods are called.

```
 prototypecell * cell = [self.CHTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(!cell)
        {
            cell = [[prototypecell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        history * hist = [history objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)indexPath.row ];
        [cell CreateFromHistory:hist];


        return cell;
```

in `HeightForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
 prototypecell * cell = [self.CHTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell CreateFromHistory:[History objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        return cell.height;
```

The createfromhistory methods sets all the uilabels text that are present inside init.

`CreateFromHistory` Method

```
 NSInteger XOriginLbl = 20;
NSInteger XOriginValue = 134;


UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};


CGSize size = [citation.date sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
[Date setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginValue, 4, Date.frame.size.width, [citation.date sizeWithAttributes:attributes].height)];
[self.dateLBL setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginLbl, 4, self.dateLBL.frame.size.width, [citation.date sizeWithAttributes:attributes].height)];
Date.text = citation.date;
self.dateLBL.text = @"Date";

Violation.numberOfLines = 0;
Violation.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
size = [citation.violation sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
[Violation setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginValue, Date.frame.origin.y + Date.frame.size.height + 2, Violation.frame.size.width, size.height)];
[self.violationLBL setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginLbl, Date.frame.origin.y + Date.frame.size.height + 2, self.violationLBL.frame.size.width, size.height)];
self.violationLBL.text = @"Violation:";
Violation.text = citation.violation;


Where.numberOfLines = 0;
Where.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
Where.text = citation.location;
[Where sizeToFit];
size = [citation.location sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
CGRect size2 = Where.frame;
[Where setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginValue, Violation.frame.origin.y + Violation.frame.size.height + 2, Where.frame.size.width,size2.size.height)];
[self.whereLBL setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginLbl, Violation.frame.origin.y + Violation.frame.size.height + 2, self.whereLBL.frame.size.width, size.height)];
self.whereLBL.text = @"Where:";



size = [citation.fine sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
[FineAmount setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginValue, Where.frame.origin.y + Where.frame.size.height + 2, FineAmount.frame.size.width, size.height)];
[self.fineLBL setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginLbl, Where.frame.origin.y + Where.frame.size.height + 2, self.fineLBL.frame.size.width, size.height)];
self.fineLBL.text = @"Fine:";
FineAmount.text = citation.fine;


Comments.numberOfLines = 2;
Comments.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
size = [citation.comments sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
[Comments setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginValue, FineAmount.frame.origin.y + FineAmount.frame.size.height + 2, Comments.frame.size.width, size.height)];
[self.commentLBL setFrame:CGRectMake(XOriginLbl, FineAmount.frame.origin.y + FineAmount.frame.size.height + 2, self.commentLBL.frame.size.width, size.height)];
self.commentLBL.text = @"Comments";
Comments.text =  citation.comments;
self.height = Comments.frame.origin.y + size.height + 2;
```

Update:
Tried to reload each sections/ each row separately, but Haven't receive positive result.

Edit and Final Update (Found work around solution)
[UILabels using constraints excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6)

Comment: Add prototypecell CreateFromHistory code for reference

Comment: remove datasource connection on from xib UITableView

Comment: suppose if you are getting this information from DB or server. usually most of do is create UI initially and then get information. So once we get information we need to reload tableview at the end then the information will be displayed try this once [tableviewobject reloaddata];

Comment: @Charan I've tried that, but the result is same...