# Adjusting length of UILabel dynamically

Tags: uilabel, autolayout, autosize, autoresizingmask

**Background:**

I faced this issue while I was implementing Localization (programatically).

**Question:**

I'm new to iOS development & I need your help. In my company, I've given a task to implement Localization to one of the Apps that I'm working on. I implemented Localization successfully with help from [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) tutorial. In my app the previous programmer had NOT used IB & Auto-Layout to develop the UI. He has done it all programatically. Now the issue is, how do I address the changing Length of the UILabels, tittles of UIbuttons ?

Solutions that I've tried:

1. applying sizeToFit on UILabel
2. setting  setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

Please guys, guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT's:**

Changed the title of the question to be more generic.

Comment: I'd edit your subject as Localization isn't a factor here. Rather you want to constraint size based on the content. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6/19657784#19657784

Comment: Hi @MaxMacLeod, thanks for your reply. I could get through this issue by doing the following

 [_myButton.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
 [_myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

Comment: that's great. If you figured it out, you can answer your own question below and mark it accepted. That will be helpful to others and also not show your question as unanswered.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod : I do not know how do I accept my answer. I read this article on stackoverflow's help center, but I dont see any kind of Check mark beside the answer toggle. May be because I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Yes you need at least 15 reputation. Then after 48 hours you can accept your own answer. Once you build up more reputation you can do it later. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer