# Fit UILabel size to its content with autolayout. Fit width and height

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout

I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6) how to fit `UILabel` height to its content. It works perfect for example if I follow suggested instruction and modify vertical **ContentHuggingPriority** and vertical **ContentCompressionResistancePriority**. So then storyboard automatically fit UILabel height to text height. If I make the same for horizontal **ContentHuggingPriority** and **ContentCompressionResistancePriority** and edit `UILabel` width constraint priority, `UILabel` fits width to text width.

My question is how to set parameters to fit size as for text height and as for text width? Because seems we can only fit or hight or width of UILabel content.

Comment: You mean maximum width and height that can be used?

Comment: @Wain, I mean that that explanation (link with Marks answer I've shared) just display how to adjust fit to content height, but I need fit to height and width also.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? `UILabel` can grow either by adding additional lines of text or by expanding its width (but at some point it won't be able to fit on the screen). You have to specify which behavior you want by using `numberOfLines` / height constraint or by setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(CGSize)findTextHeight:(float)height width:(float)width string:(NSString *)desc font:(UIFont*)font{
    if ([desc isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    CGRect textRect =[desc boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                        context:nil];
    CGSize size = textRect.size;
    return size;
}
```

This will gives you the label's size from given text and minimum height and minimum width.

Comment: so do you think there is only programmatically solution to solve this issue?