# UITableViewCell textLabel make vertically align text to be top & estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPathUITableViewCell jump on selected cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Using tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath make cell blinks . I use following code

```
-(CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 }
```

Create UITableViewCell textLabel  vertically align to be always at the top. I use following code but doesnt work.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell1 == nil) {
            cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        }

         cell1.textLabel.text = [self.itemDict objectForKey:kDESCRIPTION];
        cell1.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell1.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
        cell1.textLabel.textColor = TextColor;
         [cell1.textLabel sizeToFit];
        return cell1;
}
```

I have got as **First Image** but want **Second Image**

[image]

**I checked the following link but doesnt work out**

[Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel)

[image]

Comment: did you use autolayout? if so, you should also update constraints

Comment: ya so that I use UITableViewCell textLabel . How could we do as u say

Comment: If you are using auto layout, then you need to update the corresponding  constraints. If not, then you have to change the textLabel's frame (position) after you call `sizeToFit `.

Comment: I read that problem so i used UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1]; rather then custom cell

Comment: what can we do for UITableViewCell inbuilt cell

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16009707/2382237)

Shortly, you can achieve this by to ways - programmatically and via IB

**Using Interface Builder**

1. Set up four constraints - top, leading, trainling, height. The height constraint is mandatory.
2. Then go to the label's attributes inspector and set number of lines to 0
3. Go to the label's size inspector and increase vertical ContentHuggingPriority and vertical ContentCompressionResistancePriority.
4. Select and edit height constraint.
5. And decrease height constraint priority.

**EDIT**

Add flexible height constraint programmatically:

```
  [cell1.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell1.textLabel
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:0.0]];
```

other constraints:

```
 NSDictionary *views = @{@"textLabel":cell1.textLabel};

    [cell1.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[textLabel]|"
                          options:0
                          metrics:nil
                          views:views]];


    [cell1.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell1.textLabel
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:cell1.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:10.0]];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I read that problem so i used         UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];    rather then custom cell

Comment: what can we do for UITableViewCell inbuilt cell

Comment: remove constraint via nsarray *a = [cell1.textLabel constraints]; [cell1. removeConstraints: a]; and add programmatically consttraint with flexible height

Comment: do we need to do for   inbuilt cell too

Comment: I got this due as shown in image . Property removeConstraints not found on object type  UITableViewCell

Comment: remove dot from snippet, this is not property, this is method [cell1  removeConstraints: a];