# Move UILabel using Autolayout constrains in XIB only?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, hide, move

Possible a duplicate, but I tried could not make it work so came here.
I (new to autolayout) have two UILabel place one below each other with fixed height space.Both can increase with as per text with in it.

[image]

When First UILabel hides bottom should move to First place. How to do it using constraints in view only? I know how to do by creating IBOutlet connection of constraints for second UILabel.
EDIT: 
Given question is about more about content hugging related, where as my question is add constrains to move to first UILabel position when first hides.

Comment: whenever label hides its frame is there....means that label's frame is not removed....so just try to set frame height to 0 meanwhile label is hidden

Comment: Thanks for reply, but wanted to use constraints only. I have idea with other way work around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILabel sizeToFit doesn't work with autolayout ios6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6)

Comment: You need to work with ContentHuggingPriority and set the UILabels related to each other. Check the duplicated thread I marked this as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6

Comment: my question not about the setting hugging priority, where as it is about what constraints should I put to move second label to first label position when first label hides.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve what you want with AutoLayout is to set `constant` of all related constraints to zero. And remember **NEVER** try to set frame or bounds of your view if you are using AutoLayout(unless you override `layoutSubviews` and do the stuff in that method, which you rarely need to).

You can check out this tiny project: https://github.com/neevek/UIView-Visibility, I bet that is what you want :-)

[image]