# Why my UILabel doesn't truncate?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I already configured it from the story board to truncate tail, but it still doesn't get truncated when I set the `addressLabel.text = "something very long"`

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot - text doesn't get truncated]

Comment: You have to add constraint for address label to have horizontal spacing with contact label.

Comment: @NataMio AH you're right! thank you

Comment: May be this link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because there is no horizontal spacing between the address and the contact label, Also because address label has equal width so its taking the width of the screen and as you can see the three dots.by adding constraints should solve your issue.

Good luck !