# Calling sizeToFit() on UILabel doesn't always yield proper result in custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom tableview cell current, and I have a UILabel that is being filled with text that is multiple lines long. However, I don't want to change the size of the custom cell, so I want the UILabel to a adapt to the given size. Here is my problem though:

1. On first load of the table, the UILabel will not reflect the proper height, and won't show the word wrap for the first 3 or 4 cells
2. Once I start scrolling, the new cells reflect the proper height, and scrolling back causes the old cells to reflect the proper height.
3. If I keep scrolling back and forth, the labels shrink their width and become squished.

I am using auto layout too. Here is the code for the label as it is formatted:

```
private func assignBusAndRouteTextForIndex(card: ETACard, index: Int) {
        card.busNumberLabel.text = jsonValueForIndexAndSubscript(index, string: "rd")

        var route = jsonValueForIndexAndSubscript(index, string: "fd")
        route = route.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&amp;", withString: "&")
        print(route)

        card.routeLabel.text = route
        card.routeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        card.routeLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    private func jsonValueForIndexAndSubscript(index: Int, string: String) -> String {
        return self.items.arrayValue[index][string].description;
    }
```

And here are my auto layout constraints:
[image: AutoLayout constraints of UILabel]

And finally, my custom tableview cell class looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//Dependancies
import AnimationsFramework

class ETACard: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var card: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var busNumberLabel: UILabel!   // Contains 'Bus:'
    @IBOutlet weak var routeLabel: UILabel! // Contains 'Via:'
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: UIView!  // Contains the timing circle
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!  // Contains the arrival time

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        cardSetup()
        self.addSubview(card)
    }

    func cardSetup() {
        self.card.alpha = 1
        self.card.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.card.layer.cornerRadius = 1
        self.card.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0.2, 0.2)
        self.card.layer.shadowRadius = 1

        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.card.bounds)
        self.card.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath

        self.card.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    }

    func renderCircleForBusTime(busTime: Int) {
        ShapeRenderer.renderCircleForBusTime(circleView, busTime: busTime)
    }

    func removeCircleFromCard(view: UIView) {
        ShapeRenderer.removeRenderedCircle(view);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here are some progressive screenshots of what I am talking about. Between each screenshot is a scroll to the bottom of the list, then back up.
[image: No Scrolls]

[image: One scroll]

[image: Two scrolls]

[image: And so on...]

Please note how the text progressively shrinks and starts to get cut.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of the result which you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I found this thread on the topic:
[UILabel sizeToFit doesn't work with autolayout ios6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009405/uilabel-sizetofit-doesnt-work-with-autolayout-ios6)

It turns out that with AutoLayout, `sizeToFit` is not an option. So I went looking at my auto layout settings and saw that my bottom was set to `equal 30px` when it should be `less than or equal to 30px` so that the space under the text box can be expanded. Auto Layout should handle it as long as your sides have constraints or you have a width constraint, and you make your height `<=` some size.